# CDK - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am trying to add S3 event notification using CDK package. This CDK package deploys a lambda function in Account A to trigger everytime a S3 object is added into Account B's "testfolder/" path

```
const source_bucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketName(this, 'source_bucket', bucket_in_account_B);

  const lambdaPermission = new CfnPermission(this, "S3InvokePermission", {
      action: "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      principal: "s3.amazonaws.com",
      sourceAccount: accountId,
      sourceArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::' + bucket_in_account_B,
      functionName: this.lambdaFunction.functionName
    });

source_bucket.addEventNotification(s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, new s3n.LambdaDestination(this.lambdaFunction), {
      prefix: 'testfolder/',
      suffix: '.tsv');

source_bucket.grantReadWrite(this.lambdaFunction)
```

I have s3:PutBucketNotification and s3:GetBucketNotification in my bucket policy in Account A for the lambda role and the lambda role has AmazonS3FullAccess and AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole  policy attached.

Everything else in my code works when I comment out .addEventNotification part but when I add .addEventNotification it throws error - Error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Access Denied.

```
Bucket Policy:
{
            "Sid": "AllowBucketNotification",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "my_lambda_role"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:PutBucketNotification"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_in_account_B",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_in_account_B/*"
            ]
        }




Lambda Role Policy: This role also has AmazonS3FullAccess and AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole  policy attached. 
        {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "s3:GetObject*",
                    "s3:GetBucket*",
                    "s3:List*",
                    "s3:DeleteObject*",
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
                    "s3:PutObjectRetention",
                    "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                    "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                    "s3:Abort*"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_in_account_B",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_in_account_B/*"
                ],
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    }


{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should show how you've provided cross-account permissions.

Comment: @jarmod - I've updated it now with with more details on the policies attached to the lambda role and bucket policy. Hope this is more clear, please let me know if I should include anything else. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand what you're doing, the Lambda function potentially needs S3 permissions to the remote bucket's objects (e.g. to read the objects that trigger the Lambda function) and the IAM principal that is actually deploying the CDK stack needs permission for s3:PutBucketNotification on the remote S3 bucket (so that it can update the bucket notification configuration to add the Lambda function as an event target).

Comment: Also see [How do I set up Amazon S3 event notifications to invoke a Lambda function that's in another AWS account?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-s3-cross-account-function-invoke)

Comment: @jarmod - I've tried everything you have mentioned but still no luck :(

For you first point, the Lambda function potentially needs S3 permissions to the remote bucket's objects - IAM role associated with lambda has `list*, get* and putbucketconfiguration` policy allowing access to the remote bucket

Comment: For the second point, IAM principal that is actually deploying the CDK stack needs permission for `s3:PutBucketNotification` - I've added this permission now in every Iam roles created by my CDK stack individually.

I also went over the link and have Resource-based policy document created in lambda as stated in the document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256513/discussion-between-asim-and-jarmod).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 Bucket notifications in AWS CDK are added via a Lambda-backed custom resource. This custom resource is what needs the cross-account access.

The most straightforward way to fix this is to specify the entire account A as the principal in the Bucket policy in Account B. This is a common pattern with cross-account access - resource policies typically only include the account name to encapsulate implementation details on the other side.